# How to select a number from an array and tell you the column and row in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, select, row

If I have, for example, an array of 5 * 5 that has as numbers the list from 1 to 25 such that:

```
X = list (range (1,26))

Dimension = 5
A = np.zeros ((dimension, dimension))
N = 0
For i in range (dimension):
     For j in range (dimension):
         A [i] [j] = x [n]
         N = n + 1
```

And I want python tell me the column and row where this number 16, how is it done?

Comment: Python is case sensitive. `N` and `n` are not the same, nor are `for` and `For`

Comment: The code you are posting here is way too confusing. Do you have a running example? This is not valid python code.

Comment: do you mean: find the row & column using division and modulo or by a 2D-search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `16` in :

```
a = [[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.]
     [  6.   7.   8.   9.  10.]
     [ 11.  12.  13.  14.  15.]
     [ 16.  17.  18.  19.  20.]
     [ 21.  22.  23.  24.  25.]]
```

Do:

```
np.where(a == 16)
```

Output:

```
(array([3]), array([0]))
```